# Finding average value from polygon areas in fishnet cell based on lat/long of points using ArcGIS Pro

Tags: arcgis-pro, vector-grid, statistics, intersect

I have created a fishnet of
0.5x0.5degrees and wanted to know the average lat/long in each cell in ArcGIS Pro.

How could I accomplish that?

[image]

Comment: Overlay toolbox Intersect, then compute statistics.

Comment: i created two columns in the attribute table after the intersection, when i do the average calculation, does it automatically calculate the average within each grid?

Comment: Summary Statistics to group by intersection cell I'd.